# Is there any difference between setData and changeData?

Tags: jquery

I don't see any difference between the two functions.

Using the following JavaScript code:

```
var x = {};

$(x).bind({
  setData: function (event, key, value) {
    console.log("setData()", key, value);
  },
  changeData: function (event, key, value) {
    console.log("changeData()", key, value);
  }
});

$(x).data("key1", "alpha");
$(x).data("key1", "beta");
$(x).data("key2", "gamma");
```

... I get the following in the console:

```
setData() key1 alpha
changeData() key1 alpha
setData() key1 beta
changeData() key1 beta
setData() key2 alpha
changeData() key2 alpha
```

Both events fire every time.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what are the `setData` and `changeData` events?  I did some Googling and couldn't find anything about them...

Comment: You call both events each time so it is expected that they would both fire. While I cannot find any documentation on the functions I would guess that setData initialises and changeData modifies.

Comment: @Abe - yeah, those events aren't documented very well. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place either is called in all the code is in the data function, one is called before the set and the other right after, but the values passed in are the same.

```
$this.triggerHandler( "setData" + parts[1] + "!", args );
jQuery.data( this, key, value );
$this.triggerHandler( "changeData" + parts[1] + "!", args );
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew and topek for your quick responses. I also happend to notice that if you set "value" to an *object* and later on you  subsequently make a change a property of that object, those events don't get fired. They're only fired when you set/change the entire "value". Similarly, if you "value" is an array, and you push a few more values on to that array, the events don't fire.

Comment: `changeData` was added as previously there was no event fired after data was changed: [see original ticket 6804](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6804).

Answer (score 1):

Not a big one:

**setData** is triggered before the data is set

**changeData** is triggered after the data is set

see [jQuery/src/data.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L300-302)